# Convert matching letter-pairs in String to Uppercase, and counting conversions

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm quite new to assembly programming and need to convert two specific letter combinations in a given string to upperCase.('xx' & 'xi').but only the first combinations gets converted

For example:
str1 = "xxxx xixi" => "XXxx XIxi" and also a countervariable = 2

str2 = "abcdxx" => "abcdXX" and also a counterVariable = 1

```
lig:
    lb $t0,($a0)    #load string in $t0
    beq $t0, 0, exit    #endOfString exit
    blt $t0, 'a', next  #if char is not in alphabet ->next char
    bgt $t0, 'z', next  #if char is not in alphabet->next char
    #bne $t0, 'xx', next need to load halfword??
    bne $t0, 'x', next
    bne $t0, 'i', next
    sub $t0, $t0, 32    #convert to UpperCase
    sb $t0, ($a0)       #store back
    addi $v0,$v0, 1     #increment counterVariable
next:
    addi $a0, $a0, 1    #next character
    j lig
exit:   
    jr $ra
```

This is my first idea but it only converts single characters to upperCase not two at the same time do i need to load halfwords for that?

Any help or telling me if im on the right path is appreciated :)

Edit 1:
So i did some pseudocode and tried to implement it. (its almost the same as @Erik Eidt answer) i didnt want to post my direct homework in here so i changed the letters from 'ff' to 'xx' just fyi.

```
lig:
    lb  $t0,($a0)       #load first byte of pair
    beq $t0, 0, exit    #endOfString exit
    j   next            #jump to next function
    lb  $t1,($a0)       #load second byte of pair
    beq $t1, 0, exit    #endOfString exit
    ### Comparison ###
    bne $t0, 'f', next  #if 1st char != f
    bne $t1, 'f', else  #if 2nd char != f   
    sub $t0, $t0, 32    #convert f to F
    sub $t1, $t1, 32    #convert f to F (2nd)
    sb  $t0, ($a0)      #store byte (in place)
    sb  $t1, ($a0)      #store byte (in place)
    addi    $v0,$v0, 1  #increment counterVariable
next:
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1 #next character
    j   lig
else:
    bne $t1, 'i', next  #if 2nd char != i
    sub $t0, $t0, 32    #convert f to F
    sub $t1, $t1, 32    #convert i to I
    sb  $t0, ($a0)      #store byte (in place)
    sb  $t1, ($a0)      #store byte (in place)
    addi    $v0, $v0, 1 #increment counterVariable
    j   next            #jump to next to get new char (?)
exit:   
    jr $ra
```

My code does exactly nothing so i still have to figure out what im missing.
I guess my "next" function could be wrong or i cant compare registers with chars?

Comment: For `"xxi"`, should the `i` get upcased or not?  What if the input already has upper-case characters like `"xXxx"`, should the output be `"XXxx"` or `"xXXX"`?

Comment: Have you tried writing an algorithm in C or other language in terms of operations you can do in asm?  (Like loading a single character, not using Python regex stuff for example.)  So you can figure out the algorithm and what temp variables you need across loop iterations.

Comment: to answer the first question: "xxi" => "XXi"  and "xXxx" => "xXXX" the first apperance of xx or xi converts to UpperCase and then we jump to the next word in our String. eg. "xyzxx xixi abc" => "xyzXX XIxi abc" and counter = 2

Comment: no not yet but its probably useful to do it? i will try it now

Comment: Next "word"?  Not just the end of this letter-pair?  So after making a replacement, you have to search for a space before you start looking for a letter-pair again?  So `"xxxi xixx"` => `"XXxi XIxx"`?

Comment: its a bad description with "next word" but yes "xxxi xixx" => "XXxi XIxx"

Comment: wait a second i need to reread my task again im confused myself right now sorry

Comment: No, don't use halfwords for that, you have an array of bytes as your fundamental data structure. Sometimes you'll find that one byte and the next one are not in the same halfwords, so that will fault on this processor.  You'll have to work byte pairs as two individuals.

Comment: i asked my tutors what the right output should be for "xxxx xixi" its not quite clear from the  description of their task @PeterCordes . nonetheless i think i need to load two bytes and then do my comparison

Comment: apparently what i said first is wrong it should be "xxxx xixi" => "XXXX XIXI" and counter = 4 @PeterCordes sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok that's what I first expected, that you do all matching conversions, which makes the count more interesting.  So after a conversion, you just go to the next letter after the conversion and start looking again, not having to look for the next start-of-word (conventionally, a transition from space/punctuation to chars that can be part of a word, like upper/lower case letters and digits.  So looking for that would further complicate a task that was already complicated enough for asm beginner homework.)

Comment: @ErikEidt: Indeed, you wouldn't actually use `lh` because you need to consider unaligned halfwords, and you probably can't assume MIPS32r6 which made all loads allow unaligned.  You *could* use `lwl`/`lwr` / `andi reg,reg, 0xFFFF` to load an unaligned word and mask (if there's no risk of crossing into an unmapped page and faulting), or load bytes and shift them together like `c2<<8 | c1`.  But since both pairs you need to scan for start with `'x'`, that would be over-complicated and it's easier to just scan for an `'x'` and then check for the next char being an `x` or `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you need a state machine.  A state machine can remember patterns of input by changing between states, and before taking action — when it comes to taking action it can "undo" or ignore what was remembered (in case of incomplete match), or take action to change something (in case of complete match).

If it was me I'd work it out the simple state diagram first, then program that in C, test it in C, and then translate to assembly with confidence that it will work.

| State | Meaning | Input | Next State | Action | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | initial state | '\0' | end | none | end of string |
| 0 | initial state | 'x' | 1 | none | found 'x', partial match start |
| 0 | initial state | any but 'x' | 0 | none | no match |
| 1 | partial match 'x' | '\0' | end | none | end of string |
| 1 | partial match 'x' | 'i' | 0 | replace with XI increment counter | complete match xi |
| 1 | partial match 'x' | 'x' | 0 | replace with XX increment counter | complete match xx |
| 1 | partial match 'x' | any but 'i' or 'x' | 0 | none | incomplete match |

One way to represent states with a variable, and another is with portions of code.  If the program is in this range: it's in state 1; if that range: it's in state 2, etc..

```
char a [] = "xxxx xixi";
int counter = 0;
char *p = a;
for (;;) {
    // state 0, initial state, no partial match
    int ch = *p++;
    if ( ch == '\0' ) break; // end on null
    if ( ch == 'x' ) {
        // state 1, partial match 'x'
        ch = *p++;
        if ( ch == '\0' ) break;
        if ( ch == 'i' ) {
            p[-2] = 'X';
            p[-1] = 'I';
            counter++;
        } else if ( ch == 'x' ) {
            p[-2] = 'X';
            p[-1] = 'X';
            counter++;
        } else {
            // incomplete match
        }
    }
}
```

The above modifies the string in place, so there's no work to be done to ignore an incomplete match.  (To preserve the original input string and make a copy of the modified string instead, some copying of bytes would be necessary, and in particular, a partial match that goes incomplete would have to copy 2 characters, b/c the first copy would be suppressed.)

If you wanted to skip to a new word after a match, transition to a new state that handles characters until a space is encountered and then return to state 0.

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer it helped a lot! i posted my next try as an answer